# Analytical form of a summation

Tags: summation, stochastic-calculus, closed-form

I have a equation with a double sum. However, one of the variables in one of the sums comes from a stochastic distribution (Gaussian to be specific). How can I get a closed form equivalent of this expression? The $U$ and $T$ in the equation are constants.

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^{N_k-1} \bigg [ \big[ \sum_{i}^{N_i} \cos(\frac{4\pi}{\lambda} u_i k T) - \cos(\frac{4\pi}{\lambda} U k T) \big]^2 + \big[ \sum_{i = 1}^{N_i} \sin(\frac{4\pi}{\lambda} u_i k T) - \sin(\frac{4\pi}{\lambda} U k T) \big]^2  \bigg]$$

$$ u_i \thicksim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{u}, \sigma_{u}) $$

EDIT ========================================================

I have a simplified form now. It looks like the following

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^{N_k-1} \Bigg[ [N_i + 1] + 2 \sum_{i = 1}^{N_i} \bigg[ \sum_{m = 1}^{N_i} \cos(\frac{4\pi}{\lambda} (u_i - u_m) k T ) - \cos( \frac{4\pi}{\lambda} (u_i - U) k T) \bigg] \Bigg]$$

$$ u_i \thicksim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{u}, \sigma_{u}) $$
$$ u_m \thicksim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{u}, \sigma_{u}) $$

I want a function that looks like this $f(U, N_i, N_k, \mu_u, \sigma_u)$

Comment: Is there a reason to expect this has a closed form? Also what is $U$? A constant or another random variable?

Comment: Yes, the reason why I need a closed form of the equation is that I want to estimate the parameters of the Gaussian distribution ($\mu_{u}$ and $\sigma_u$). They are not directly used in the model. So, I need to get a closed form. $U$ is a constant indeed.

Comment: first of all you can simplify the $\cos ^2 + \sin ^2$ ..

Comment: Yes, I am working on a simplified model and will update the question shortly.

Comment: It is ready. I have edited it. I can see it can be solved with some probabilistic ideas. I can't think straight with distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*-- following my comment above --*

and then proceed with
and then proceed with
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N_k  - 1} {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N_i } {\left( {2 - 2\left( {\cos \alpha \cos \beta  + \sin \alpha \sin \beta } \right)} \right)} }  =  \\ 
  = 2\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N_k  - 1} {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N_i } {\left( {1 - \cos \left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)} \right)} }  =  \\ 
  = 2\left( {N_k N_i  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N_k  - 1} {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N_i } {\cos \left( {\alpha  - \beta } \right)} } } \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

But the cosine of a (non-central) gaussian variable does not have a simple form (to my knowledge).

Unless you have that "most probably" $ u_i <<U$, in which case you can approximate the $\cos$ by series expansion.